# How to compute this Z-Value?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I need to compute $z_{0.05}$. I check my statistics table and the value is $0.5199$ but in my example it says the value is $1.645$. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are treating $0.05$ as a $z$-score, but you should be treating it as an area.

Comment: Oh you are right, I sub in $0.05$ into inverse normal on my calculator and obtain the correct result. I should have just looked for the value in my table that gives a probability close to $0.95$. Thanks!